# mapping certain columns of grid view to DataTable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have a grid view from which I have to map to DataTable using only some of the columns of the Gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomerOderGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField Visible="false" DataField="ID"/>                                        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No.">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="NAME"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CUSTOMER_NUM" HeaderText="CONTACT"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QUANTITY">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="text" runat="server" id="QUANTITY"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ADDRESS" DataField="ADDRESS"></asp:TemplateField>        
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

From this grid I want `ID, QUANTITY, ADDRESS` to map in DataTable. I have already created a DataTable "`dt_cust_order`" with columns `ID, QUANTITY, ADDRESS`. But how can I map or fill data of these certain columns from this grid to the `DataTable`.

Comment: Do you ask how to export DataTable from datasource of GridView ?

Comment: No, exporting only certain columns of grid view to DataTable.